# ie7 killing list-style on floated ul's

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have two ul's (.listone and .listtwo respectfully) floated left and the other right. The list-style:circle; works in every browser except for ie7 =< . In ie7 the list-style is just ignored. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `list-style: inside circle;`
It may be a margin thing with floating lists, inside circle seems to work for me because the bullet gets rendered inside the block box.

http://www.highdots.com/forums/cascading-style-sheets/lists-floats-invisible-list-style-234181.html